# Can't get Data from json object

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, django

I have this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function requestimg(username){
                $.ajax({
                    url: '{% url "image" %}',
                    data: {
                      'username': username
                    },
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data) {
                            //Printing the whole data
                            console.log(data);
                            //Printing to see where I am
                            console.log("Name: ");
                            //Trying to rint the name
                            console.log(data[0].nombre);
                        }else {
                             alert("May Day");
                        }
                    }
                });
        }
```

I have a problem reading the properties in the json object
When i print the data I get this:

```
{
    json: "[
        {
            "model": "polls.imagen",
            "pk": 17,
            "fields": {
                "n…"36",
                "imagen": "polls/static/pictures/dr.jpg"
            }
        }
    ]"
}
```

And when i print the data as I have it on the code i get:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nombre' of undefined
```

I have tryied writing it like `data.nombre` but i just get `undefined`

I have also tried this `console.log(data[0].fields);` , `data[0].model`, `data.model`

**IMPORTANT** I want to clarify that i wont know why there are 2 json objects im supposed to get just one and even if i try to put a [1] instead of the [0] i get the same mistakes.

I've tried answers from some previous similar questions and they didn't help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json).

Comment: technically you should be able to access the `nombre` field with `data[1].fields.nombre` (it seems to be the second item in the array, so `data[1]` not `data[0]`)

Comment: @donnikitos I have tried that and it says Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fields' of undefined

Comment: @JoseRamon I just unfolded your response, try `data[0].json[0].fields.nombre` that should do it

Comment: @donnikitos Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'json' of undefined, I've tried it with `data[0]`, `data[1]`, `data[n].json[n]`

Comment: @JoseRamon what is `data.json` giving you? your console.log is not very clear. Is it one response or two?

Comment: @donnikitos `[{"model": "polls.imagen", "pk": 17, "fields": {"nombre": "55", "pub_date": "2017-08-08T05:52:38Z", "tecninca": "yyyy", "tamano": "yyyyyyyy", "precio": "yyyyy", "size": "36", "imagen": "polls/static/pictures/dr.jpg"}}]`, if i try `data.json.fields` it gives me undefined

Comment: @JoseRamon can you try this `data.json[0].fields.nombre` and see what value it returns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will be able to access the fields per

```
data.json[0].fields
```

the response of your url is an array, named **json**

Additionally `data.json` is returning a string, so convert it to JSON with

```
data.json = JSON.parse(data.json);
```

Comment: Okay if I use that it says `undefined` but thanks to that I have a new clue, if I use `data.json[0]` it returns me `[` which i guess is because it is taking this as a string, if I put `data.json[3]` I get the `m` from `model`

Comment: @JoseRamon then you can use JSON.parse(data.json)  to convert it to proper json

Comment: Finally, Thanks a lot

Comment: @JoseRamon or set in `jQuery.ajax({dataType: 'json'})`

Comment: Yeah @JoseRamon covert it into a JSON first do this `JSON.parse(data.json)`

Answer (score 0):

Convert it to JSON first `JSON.parse(data.json)`

This will give you the access to the fields object `data.json[0].fields`

Comment: read my replay to donnikitos above I still have a issue if I use that